# Multiple entities send in Post Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Hi I am trying to add a review to a location by an user

I have the following code in my Bll

```
public void AddReview(Guid locationId, ReviewDto review, UserDto user)
        {
            var location = _locationRepository.Get(locationId);
            var reviewModel = new Review
            {
                Comment = review.Comment,
                Rate = review.Rate,
                Location = location,
                LocationId = location.Id,
                User = new User
                {
                    Name = user.Name,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Password = user.Password
                },
                UserId = user.Id

            };
            _reviewRepository.Add(reviewModel);
            _reviewRepository.Save();
            location.AddReview(reviewModel);

        }
    }
```

It's possible to sent User and Review both from Post ?

How U.R.I. should look like .. I think about 
/api/location/{id}/review/user (POST)....I don't know , I would appreciate some Help ..Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be POSTing that exact payload at

```
/api/location/{id}/review
```

I'd say you'd only use the /user endpoint when *accessing* that resource, because it would be weird POSTing a review (basically) to the user endpoint. If you're talking about REST [level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), you could have a link from the review to the user. Alternatively you could simply embed the user inside the review resource as to get them both in one call.

That being said, the most orthodox approach would probably adding them in steps (add a review, go to the resource, follow some sort of user-add relationship and POST a user.

Comment: I suppose the user is already posted , is logged in , and he add's a review to a location.... My reviewDto has a LocationId and a UserId

Comment: then I'd imagine it the other way around: navigate to User, then follow a review-add relationship, POSTing just the Review (the userId can also be inferred from the url, not necessarily from the body)